# How can I create extra columns without going out of RAM, and then use it for ML algorithms?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, dask, ram

I have a dataset with 3m+ (ordered) rows, and 100 columns, which I can load into my notebook using Pandas. I would like to append about 900 columns which are calculated using the 100 existing columns. The end goal is to train several machine learning models (NN's, Random Forests).

When I try to append the columns using Pandas, my machine breaks down due to insufficient RAM (I have 25GB). Therefore, I tried to use Dask, which allows me to compute the 900 columns without problems. However, Dask dataframes cannot be used as input for Random Forests (Sklearn) and Keras models, so I guess at some point you have to convert it back to a pandas dataframe.

I am quite stuck at this point. Speed is quite important because I need refit the models often. Does anyone have some good suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to "shrink" datatypes in pandas if possible, like using uint8 if the columns contains an integer less than 255 etc..

You can find the max value of a datatype suing numpy  : numpy.finfo() for float datatypes (float16/32/64) and numpy.iinfo() for integer datatypes ([u]int8/16/32/64)

[pandas read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

you can also use pandas read_csv chunksize option, if you can save data as a csv, and so iterate on your csv file

you can also combine the 2 methods !

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't solve my problems. I already shrank the datatypes, and the chunksize option is too slow for model training.

Comment: well then the only way to is to add RAM to your machine or train your model on a GCP vm with sufficient memory

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do ML on a larger-than-RAM dataset then Dask-ML https://ml.dask.org/ may give you what you need. It also has integrations to many common 3rd party tools.

Note that lots of libraries that work with in-RAM data will not work well with out-of-RAM data, typically you only get a subset of ML libraries that work well on out-of-RAM data. An alternative is to build many models, each on a subsample of the data (e.g. split your data into N DataFrames, each of which fits into RAM, then build a model on each one at a time, then combine the predictions from each model as a later step).

Do you really need all 900 columns? One test might be to sub-sample a set of rows (e.g. 100k) with 900 columns and build an RF sklearn model, then ask the model "which columns are most useful?". Maybe you only need a subset of all of the columns and you can discard the rest? Dask can extract a subsample of rows and/or columns to a CSV or Parquet file which Pandas can read back.

Maybe you don't need a powerful model like RF or ANN? If a linear model will do then Dask's ML or a tool like https://vowpalwabbit.org/ might do the job.

Do also think about upgrading your RAM - the developer time spent learning a new tool (like Dask ML) is probably much more expensive than renting a temporary Amazon big-box that has more than enough RAM for your experiments.

Comment: I really need all columns and these models, so Dask ML does not help because RF is not available. I will consider renting a powerful VM, thanks.

Comment: Do you need RF (only) or can you use something like XGBoost? XGBoost is available in Dask ML, I've never used it but have just read various pages of background. It sounds like it'll do bigger-than-RAM training just fine, see https://ml.dask.org/xgboost.html and https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2032 for history

Comment: Yes, I need Random Forests only. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you could indulge my curiosity - why RF in preference to XGBoost (or other GBM)? Arguably GBMs will generally beat RF on the same dataset.

Comment: It's for research purposes